.NET Core Img Issue
I want to upload my image. The uploading process is working, but when I tried to show my image on front side, it's not working, only rendering a disabled <img> sign.
ProductController.cs:
public IActionResult Upsert(int? id)
{
       ProductVM productVM = new()
       {
           CategoryList = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
           {
               Text = u.Name,
               Value = u.Id.ToString()
           }),
           Product = new Product()
       };

       if (id == null || id == 0)
       {
           // create
           return View(productVM);
       }
       else
       {
           // update
           productVM.Product = _unitOfWork.Product.Get(u => u.Id == id);
           return View(productVM);
       }
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult Upsert(ProductVM productVM,IFormFile? file)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           string wwwRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;

           if (file != null)
           {
               string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
               string productPath = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, @"images\product");

               using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(productPath, fileName),FileMode.Create))
               {
                   file.CopyTo(fileStream);
               }

               productVM.Product.ImageURL = @"\images\product\" + fileName;              
           }

           _unitOfWork.Product.Add(productVM.Product);
           _unitOfWork.Save();

           TempData["success"] = "Product created successfully";

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       else
       {
           productVM.CategoryList = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
           {
               Text = u.Name,
               Value = u.Id.ToString()
           });

           return View(productVM);
       }
}

Upsert.cshtml:
<div class="col-2">
    <img src="/@Model.Product.ImageURL" width="100%" style="border-radius:5px; border:1px solid #bbb9b9" />
</div>

I tried different variations but it's not working.
I want to show image of my product on the frontend page means in upsert.cshtml but image is not being shown

In the browser hit F12, go to the network tab, then it the endpoint and see if there is a problem. And if so, you can probably see details as to why there are problems.

GET https://localhost:44382/images/productd600ce5d-ffba-4e19-be22-e7494f5f3640.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Is that the path and filename you were expecting?

I assume that when you say, "the uploading process is working" that you mean the file saves to the directory you specified and with the expected filename.  If so, then look at the source html for the rendered page. Find the <img ...> tag and check that the src attribute is properly formed and is properly html encoded.

It's path issue, now your url is
https://localhost:44382/images/productd600ce5d-ffba-4e19-be22-e7494f5f3640.jpg

It's wrong, the correct url should be
https://localhost:44382/images/product/d600ce5d-ffba-4e19-be22-e7494f5f3640.jpg

So please use my modified sample code below to fix it.
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    string wwwRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;

    if (file != null)
    {
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        // Use Path.Combine like below
        string productPath = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, "images", "product");

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(productPath, fileName), FileMode.Create))
        {
            file.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }

        // Change you path like below
        productVM.Product.ImageURL = "/images/product/" + fileName;
    }

    _unitOfWork.Product.Add(productVM.Product);
    _unitOfWork.Save();

    TempData["success"] = "Product created successfully";

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

And use it in .cshtml.
<div class="col-2">
    <img src="@Model.Product.ImageURL" width="100%" style="border-radius:5px; border:1px solid #bbb9b9" />
</div>


thanks all, it work the issue is that i was using forward slashes but backward slashes are required

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
